# How to realize blocking UI for non-standard confirm() function?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I'm going to realize custom function `confirm` for the site. And what is better way to do it? Of course I could use `ok` and `cancel` callbacks, but I also want to use structure like:

```js
if ( confirm('something') ) {
    // some action
}
```

And I don't want provide infinity loop...
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Until shadow DOM becomes a well-implemented standard, your best bet is ok/cancel callbacks.

Comment: You can't create a "blocking" interface. What you can do however is deactivate everything else on your page except for the "OK" and "Cancel" (or whatever) in your dialog.

Comment: Well just "click" handlers on buttons, or something like that. You show the element, fade the rest of the page, and wait for "Ok" or "Cancel" to be clicked.